# clean urls in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Im using page.php in wordpress for making a dynamic page.

Right now Im using photography/?cat=portraits

But I want photography/portraits

Im currently grabbing whatever is in my query string (cat=portraits) and only showing that content.

Where at in wordpress can I set up the routes or permalinks to be formated more simple?

Answer (score 0):

Permalinks can be found under the setting tab from your WordPress admin interface

Follow this tutorial...

http://www.creativecitrus.com/wordpress-development/how-to-get-pretty-urls-in-wordpress

Or theres the Pretty URL plugin....but Ive never used that

http://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-url/

Answer (score 0):

Login wp-admin

Settings -> permalinks and choose custom structure place this sting and save it

/%category%/%postname%

If you have any problem in saving permalink please copy paste it in htaccess.

Or make it write permission for period.

Comment: im not using blog posts or wordpress's categories. I am using a NextGen Gallery Plugin where I can make categories and upload images within that. What other options do I have to choose from besides category and postname?